# Use Quadpy to numerically integrate sets of points on a Sphere

Tags: python, numpy, math, numerical-integration

I have a set of values on a sphere in three dimensions. I want to numerically integrate them, and I heard that quadpy offers good speed and functionality. However, I do not have a function

```
def func(x, y, z):
   do something
   return f
```

which I could pass to quadpy. Can I just use its integration somehow to numerically integrate my set of points with one of their schemes? Otherwise, if someone knows a good, and fast numpy or scipy alternative I'd be also OK with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quadpy author here. All methods in quadpy are Gaussian integration. meaning that you *must* be able to evaluate a function at given points. (The magic in Gaussian integration is how the points are chosen.)

If you only have numerical data here and there, the best you can do is probably form Voronoi cells, i.e., for each point `i` compute the area `V_i` that is closest to this point, and then

```
sum(V_i f(x_i))
```

As an approximation, you can use [meshzoo](https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo#sphere-surface) to create a spherical mesh and assign the triangles to their closest `x_i`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So far I just used trapezoidal method in spherical coordinates to integrate over phi and then theta, but I will try you suggestion and compare!

Comment: That's also a good idea. Perhaps even a better one. Remember the $r$ due to the coordinate transformation.